# Adding a box-shadow effect for each row

Tags: jquery, html, css

The shadow effect on my `<div>` box is not rendering properly.

Please check out http://wordpresswixdemo.novigolabs.in/?page_id=12; it is a normal table with a `<div>` tag inside each column. Using CSS, I gave them a grid-like effect, but `box-shadow` doesn't work properly; it breaks on each column.

```
.grid tbody tr td div.glow {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px -5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px -5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px -5px #888;
}

.grid tbody tr td:last-child div.glow {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px -5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px -5px #888 ;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px -5px #888 ;
}
```

Rounded corners with broad borders is not possible in case of tr-td table. I have almost all of the possible combination of numbers in the above CSS.

Comment: you add the shadow to each td in the tr. try to add the shadow only to the tr element

Comment: I need rounded corners and space between each row, it seems it is not possible together in case of td's. I spent whole in researching but couldn't find any thing

Comment: hm ok than try to make the shadow bigger on the right site for each td, but not the last-one `last-child`.

Comment: I tried that also.. but in this case column borders are becoming visible, which I don't want. It should look like a box

Comment: Ok, is on hold, but I have a answer for you. Don`t use table, use lists (UL LI), I made an example hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/cYede/

Comment: @Mattos I am using datatable plugin to insert this content from wordpress backend. That plugin is fulfillng all my functional requirement only problem is there with this shadow effect, otherwise all are fine. BTW your example is really nice I will use it in designing some other page.